# Use sscanf for regex purpose

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I have a string `str`, if `str` is composed of pure digits, then extract the digits into an `int`, if not, extract nothing or just 0.

For example,

```
str = "12345";  // composed of pure digits, extract 12345
str = "123abc";  // not pure digits, extract nothing or 0
```

Can I do it using `sscanf`? How?

Comment: How should negative numbers be handled? @perreal's solution flunks on them; mine succeeds.

Comment: To the OP: what if the number is too big, e.g., `12345678901234567890` (which exceeds even 63-bit `int`)? @StilesCrisis: that's a good question, although "pure digits" sounds like negative numbers are disallowed.

Comment: @torek, well, negative numbers are allowed

Comment: Recommend to put later requirements like "negative numbers are allowed" in the post.

Answer (score 2):

```
int  value;
char unused;
if (1 == sscanf(myString, "%d%c", &value, &unused))
{
    // success
}
else
{
    // bad input
}
```

Comment: Given that negative values *are* allowed (per latest comment), this is the simplest way to use `sscanf` to do the job.  The behavior with out of range (too-big or too-negative-big) digit sequences is not defined, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int only_int(const char *s, int *v) {
    char buf[256];
    *v = 0;
    if (sscanf(s, "%[0-9]", buf) && strlen(buf) == strlen(s)) {
        *v = atoi(buf);
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main() {
    char str1[] = "12345", str2[] = "123abc";
    int i, r;
    r = only_int(str1, &i); printf("%d, %d\n", r, i);
    r = only_int(str2, &i); printf("%d, %d\n", r, i);
    return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

```
 0, 12345
-1, 0
```

Comment: What happens in `only_int()` if the `sscanf()` fails?  For example, the first character in the string is not a digit?  You run `strlen()` on a variable with undefined content.  It probably won't cause too many problems, but it isn't ideal, I think.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to consider:

1. Should only digits be accepted or are negative values okay?
2. Should it check for out-of-bound values?

This would perform a decent amount of validation and range checking:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

unsigned long parse_num(const char* str)
{
    char *endptr = NULL;
    long result;

    if (strspn(str, "0123456789") != strlen(str)) {
        return 0;
    }

    errno = 0;
    result = strtoul(str, &endptr, 10);

    if (errno == ERANGE || *endptr) {
        return 0;
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%lu\n", parse_num("12345")); // 12345
    printf("%lu\n", parse_num("123abc")); // 0
    printf("%lu\n", parse_num("-123")); // 0
    printf("%lu\n", parse_num("1231111111111111111111111111111123123131")); // 0
    printf("%lu\n", parse_num("0123")); // 123
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Pure Digits using sscanf()**
`" %n"` to detect leading white space.
`"%d"` scan the `int`.
`"%c"` to test for trailing characters.

```
int PureDigits(const char *s) {
   int y;
   char extra;
   int n;
   if ((1 == sscanf(s, " %n%d%c", &n, &y, &extra)) && (n == 0)) {
     return y; // success
     }
   return 0; // failed
 }
```